# Copy, Cut, Select, Select buttons are in black colour

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This is Very very strange bug. i don't know why but all the system button copy/cut/select .... change their colour.

[image]

BTW: in IOS 7 the button is ok.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Do you use method swizzling in your app?

Comment: i do use this SBTextField and EDTextField. they have drawPlaceholderInRect and drawTextInRect.

Comment: I don't know about those components, but check our 'method swizzling' and make sure that's not happening - it could very well cause that issue